# Can't bind v-on:click on Vuetify [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to bind a click event on dynamically generated subheader v-list-tile Vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/subheaders but each time I click the option an error appears.

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"

found in

---> <VListTile>
       <VList>
         <VCard>
           <VApp>
             <Root>
```

I have tried adding the methods forcibly (without passing object) and it works. It just triggers when it is passed to an object and dynamically rendered.

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/menthos984/pen/NZYQwm) of the bug I encountered.

What I am expecting is to trigger the method that is called without triggering an error

Comment: There are a few issues with your code - `methods` is inside your data, whereas it should be top level; by calling `click: 'triggerClick(1)'`, you've just declared that as a String and not a function (which is throwing the error you've mentioned) - this needs to be changed to `click: this.triggerClick(1)` in order to compile, but it won't do what you want it to do. Please edit your code into your question itself, as external links are not permanent and could become worthless if the link changes/dies.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My methods are inside the Data object. They should be at the same level.

In the [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/kimsanka/pen/OeZLZy) take the function name out of the data object and only left the number `id`.

By calling the function on the `@click` event and passing the number there made the method work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was listening to an event emitted from a child component and doing nothing with the received value:

```
<my-component @hide="show" v-if="show"/>
```

I should change the value when the value was received:

```
<my-component @hide="show = $event" v-if="show"/>
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I coded something similar on a HTML tag:

```
@something="colorList"
```

Where `colorList` was a javascript object array. Instead, you have to write a function the value is passed to, and set the value inside the function:

```
<... @something="updateColorList" ...>
```

And in `methods`

```
updateColorList(newColorParameter): {
    this.colorList = newColorParameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I had defined a variable and method of same name.

```
<script>
  data: {
     toggleSideBar: flase,
  },
  methods: {
   toggleSideBar() {
    this.toggleSideBar = !this.toggleSideBar;
   },
  }
</script>
```

**Solution:**
I changed name of method, so that it is different from variable.